# Can I open old Visual Studio Solutions (2005,2008, 2010,2013) in Visual Studio 2015 without upgrading the projects?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I read on [Scott Hanselman's Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2015ReleasedPlusASPNET5Roadmap.aspx), "I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to edit even .NET 2.0 apps so I'm not using older versions of VS," .

I also support old .Net solutions that open in previous versions of Visual Studio (2005, 2008, 2010, 2013). Is it possible with VS2015 to open these old solutions with out upgrading them?

I don't mind if they don't target the latest framework, it would just be handy to use a single version of Visual Studio rather than have 5 versions installed side by side.

Comment: What's the harm in converting them?

Comment: Yes, that usually works.  If it doesn't then it will let you know.  The only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: I appreciate that converting them is an option and have done this on a few frequently used projects. But on the really old stuff I fear that moving to newer frameworks may introduce bugs in the code. It's code I inherited (knowledge is lacking), there's a lot of it and it's not broken, so I don't want to risk breaking it unnecessarily. Even if I did convert it I wouldn't be able to test it all (too big / complex).

Comment: @Fordy Then what harm it is to avoid using the new IDE at all.

Comment: @LexLi There is no harm in avoiding the new IDE. It's just that I have to install 4 version of Visual Studio to support the current projects (5 if you include VS2015). I would much rather install 1 version, VS2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VS2015 to open or change apps that use older .NET framework (without having to upgrade to newer .NET framework).

[Visual Studio Multi-Targeting Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb398197.aspx)

[How to: Target a Version of the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb398202.aspx)

Also, you can install VS2015 and run it side by side older VS.

Comment: The links do provide an answer, although it’s not exactly risk free. 
MSDN says:  _“When you open a project that targets an earlier version of the .NET Framework, Visual Studio can automatically upgrade it **or leave the target as is.**”_  - So I’m thinking great I can use it to target my old projects.  But _“Framework targeting does not guarantee that your application will run correctly. You must test your application to make sure it runs against the targeted version.”_  - So you can do it but there’s a risk your application will not work correctly.

Comment: @Fordy, I think this is just an MS way of making you TEST your projects anyway, just to be on the safe side, rather than just relying on MS "because I said so". It's a way to put you off from avoiding to test your projects, IMO.